# how to query builder select inside select on laravel

Tags: jquery, postgresql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have some trouble with Laravel Query Builder. I want to convert this SQL Query:

```
select (select sum(amount) from transactions t
            join sale w on w.id = t.sale_id
            join types s on s.id = w.type_id
            where s.name = 'Bronze'
        ) as sum_amount
    from transactions
    limit 1;
```

How to implement this query on my laravel query builder ?
I'm using laravel 5.2

hope someone help me :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DB::table('transactions')
  ->select(DB::raw("(select sum(amount) from transactions t
      join sale w on w.id = t.sale_id
      join types s on s.id = w.type_id
      where s.name = 'Bronze'
  ) as sum_amount"))
  ->take(1)
  ->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @IrwanSunario - If you find this answer helpful and correct then please accept & upvote this answer as this motivates me to answer other questions like this and also helps others to find the right answer quickly!

Comment: i want ask one question again, i want add something like where s.name = 'Bronze' and left(t.week, 2) between 1 and 13

i want using between on that where, how rastogi ?

Comment: Didn't get you!

Comment: i want add on where left(t.week, 2) between 1 and 13